# Stuck in else if loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I'm doing an exercise for a class and we are creating a Todo list.

My issue is that when I type in my Todo and press enter, I get the message `Enter new Todo`, instead of `Added todo`.

It seems I'm stuck in this `else if` loop and it won't go to the next else `if` statement.

```js
var todos = ["Buy New Turtle"];

window.setTimeout(function() {

  var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

  while(input !== "quit") {

    if(input === "list") {
      console.log("**********");
      todos.forEach(function(todo, i) {
        console.log(i + ": " + todo);
      })
      console.log("**********")
    }
    else if(input === "new") {
      var newTodo = prompt("Enter new todo");
      todos.push(newTodo);
      console.log("Added todo");
      }

    else if(input === "delete"){
      var index = prompt("Enter index of todo to delete");
      todos.splice(index, 1);
      }
  }
    input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

  console.log("OK, YOU QUIT THE APP");
}, 500);
```

Comment: You never check the `input` again (until after the `while` exits), so the `while` loops forever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the redeclaration of `input` inside the `while` loop. Also check if `input` is truthy - that way if someone closes the prompt box it doesn't crash.

```js
var todos = ["Buy New Turtle"];

window.setTimeout(function() {

  var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

  while (input !== "quit" && input) {

    if (input === "list") {
      console.log("**********");
      todos.forEach(function(todo, i) {
        console.log(i + ": " + todo);
      })
      console.log("**********")
    } else if (input === "new") {
      var newTodo = prompt("Enter new todo");
      todos.push(newTodo);
      console.log("Added todo");
    } else if (input === "delete") {
      var index = prompt("Enter index of todo to delete");
      todos.splice(index, 1);
    }

    input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
  }

  console.log("OK, YOU QUIT THE APP");
}, 500);
```

Comment: You beat me to it, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

`input = prompt("What would you like to do?");` is outside of your `while` loop, so everytime you enter a todo, the `input` variable always has the value of "new".

Look at the attached snippet for corrections:

```js
var todos = ["Buy New Turtle"];

window.setTimeout(function() {

  var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

  while(input !== "quit") {

    if(input === "list") {
      console.log("**********");
      todos.forEach(function(todo, i) {
        console.log(i + ": " + todo);
      })
      console.log("**********")
    }
    else if(input === "new") {
      var newTodo = prompt("Enter new todo");
      todos.push(newTodo);
      console.log("Added todo");
    }
    else if(input === "delete"){
      var index = prompt("Enter index of todo to delete");
      todos.splice(index, 1);
    }
    // this line was moved into the while loop  
    input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
  }
    
  console.log("OK, YOU QUIT THE APP");
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var todos = ["Buy New Turtle"];
newTodo = [];

window.setTimeout(function() {

  var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

  while(input !== "quit") {

    if(input === "list") {
      console.log("**********");
      todos.forEach(function(todo, i) {
        console.log(i + ": " + todo);
      })
      console.log("**********")
    }
    else if(input === "new") {
      var newTodo = prompt("Enter new todo");
      todos.push(newTodo);
      console.log("Added todo");
      }

    else if(input === "delete"){
      var index = prompt("Enter index of todo to delete");
      todos.splice(index, 1);
      }
    input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
  }


  console.log("OK, YOU QUIT THE APP");
}, 500);`enter code here`
```